# Pdfpages cannot find file

Tags: pdfpages

I'm learning how to use `pdfpages` correctly. Unfortunately, my machine repeatedly tells me `Unable to load pictures or PDF file '/Users/anonymous/Desktop/test.pdf`. I have to confess that I don't have any idea to solve this situation. Could you give me some instructions about this matter?

- TeXShop version 4.44
- MacOS Catalina version 10.15.1
- XeLaTex (typeset)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1-3]{/Users/anonymous/Desktop/test.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the simplest case is to put `test.pdf` in the same folder as the document and use  `\includepdf[pages=1-3]{test.pdf}` check that works first.

Comment: Thank you David! Unfortunately, I got the same answer when I tried at first. That's why I  approached differently as seen above.

Comment: put test.pdf in your folder, compile and then show the log-file.

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer, I understand what you told me just now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, I just understand what you explained. Thank you very much!